# Misunderstanding of $\epsilon$-neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am given the following definition of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood:

Given a real number $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and a positive number $\epsilon>0$, the set

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x-a|<\epsilon \}$$

is called the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a.

The book says that the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a consists of all those points whose distance from a is less than $\epsilon$. I don't understand how $|x-a|<\epsilon$ says that though. To my understanding $|x-a|<\epsilon$ says that

$$-\epsilon<x-a<\epsilon$$
$$-x-\epsilon<-a<\epsilon-x$$
$$x+\epsilon>a>x-\epsilon$$
$$x-\epsilon<a<x+\epsilon$$

Could someone please reconcile my understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: $-\epsilon<x-a<\epsilon\implies a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon$

Comment: @Mark: How do you define the distance between two reals $x$ and $a$?

Comment: $|x-a|$ is *defined* as the distance between $x$ and $a$.

Comment: @Mark: Your inequalities are _mathematically true_, but semantically anomalous, since $a$ is fixed and $x$ is constrained. As Ivo's answer shows, you want to do exactly your calculation, but with the roles of $a$ and $x$ swapped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to write it this way: $$|x-a|<\epsilon \iff -\epsilon < x-a < \epsilon \iff a-\epsilon < x < a+\epsilon$$And the last expression means that $x \in \left]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon\right[$. The neighbourhood is centered in $a$, not $x$. The moral of the history is that $|x-a|<\epsilon$ if and only if $x \in \left]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon\right[$. So: $$\{x \in \Bbb R \mid |x-a|<\epsilon\} = \left]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon\right[. $$