# What does "$\epsilon$" mean in this formula

Tags: analysis, multisets

I have started seeing the "$\epsilon$" symbol in this paper. What exactly does $\epsilon$ it mean in the formula?

The hard part is this definition: "Range$(p,\epsilon)=\{o\mid ||p,o||_2\leq \epsilon,o \in \mathbb{R}^d\}$."
I don't know what $\epsilon$ means here.
[FORMULA IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5bex.png)

Comment: That is the Greek letter epsilon $\epsilon$, which is different from $\in$.

Comment: @runway44 That's an answer. Why put it in the comment section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol is called "epsilon," and is simply a variable, just like $x$ or $y$. However, note that $\epsilon$ is most commonly used in analysis as an arbitrarily small (but positive) value.

If you are new to the idea of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood, check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305857/misunderstanding-of-epsilon-neighborhood).

Be sure not to confuse "$\epsilon$" with "$\in$", which means "element of." These symbols both looks like "e"s, but have much different meanings!

Comment: Thank you very much

The two symbols look similar, so I had no idea it was epsilon.

Saved a lot of time thanks for the help

Comment: Happy to help! Keep reading math papers! It's one of the best way to improve your mathematical understanding, especially in regards to notation.

Comment: As an aside, the $\in$ takes its basic shape from the Greek letter $\epsilon$. The symbol $\in$ means "is an element of", so using the Greek letter that starts the word "element" as a design inspiration isn't entirely unreasonable.